# Move element at the end of a space of memory allocated with malloc

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, memmove

I allocated a space of memory with malloc (to have a matrix) and I have to move the "row" at the end, I tried this:

```
double **dataset = fill_dataset(....);

double* temp = malloc((d + 1) * sizeof(double ));
for (int i = 0; i < d + 1; i++) {
     temp[i] = dataset[0][i];
}
memmove(&dataset[0], &dataset[1], (p_in_retained  -  1) * sizeof(double *));

for (int i = 0; i < d + 1; i++) {
     dataset[p_in_retained - 1][i] = temp[i];
}
```

p_in_retained is the number of rows, the problem is that when the second loop ends I have the same element in the last and the second to last element, for example, suppose that this is the initial matrix:

```
id col1 col2 
 1    1   1
 2    6   3
 3    8   2
 4    9   1
```

what I expect to have is the following:

```
id col1 col2 
 2    6   3
 3    8   2
 4    9   1
 1    1   1
```

what I get is:

```
id col1 col2 
 2    6   3
 3    8   2
 1    1   1
 1    1   1
```

Comment: What are id and col1 and col2? Show the array declaration. That is provide a minima complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @VladfromMosow It's not important, the allocation is only about the numbers, so there are 4 rows.

Comment: what type is `dataset`? Is it pointer to pointer? Or is it array of arrays?

Comment: @user253751, I edited the question to include this, it is a pointer to pointer

Comment: so after you do the memmove, that means the last two rows in dataset are the same pointer?

Comment: @user253751, maybe, I don't know

Comment: @SImoneRusso please know what your code is doing. The fact that dataset is not a 2D array, but actually a (pointer to a) 1D array of pointers to more 1D arrays is quite relevant.

Comment: @SimoneRusso if I have an array of pointers and I run this memmove instruction what do you expect that it does to the array? It copies the 2nd to the 1st, the 3rd to the 2nd, etc, the last to the second-to-last, and leaves the last one alone. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is @user253751

Comment: @SimoneRusso so after you do that, the last two items in the array would be the same, right?

Comment: After memmove, it shoud have row with id = 1 as the last element. I write what I expect to obtain and what instead I obtain in the question

Comment: there are no rows because this is a 1D array. The items in the array are pointers. The last two items in the array would be the same, right?

Comment: No, the last to element must not be the same

Comment: My doubt is, have i to use &dataset or dataset in memmove? What is the difference in the two case

Comment: @SimoneRusso it depends what you are trying to move

Answer (score 0):

Array od pointers (ie double pointer).

```
void rotateRow(size_t rows, int **data)
{
    int *temp = data[0];
    if(rows > 1)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < rows - 1; i ++) 
            data[i] = data[i + 1];
        data[rows - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Real 2D array
Use pointers to arrays. It makes it much easier

malloc version:

```
void rotateRow(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
   
    int (*temp)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if(temp)
    {
        memcpy(temp, array[0], sizeof(*array));
        memmove(array[0], array[1], sizeof(*array) * (rows - 1));
        memcpy(array[rows - 1], temp, sizeof(*array));
    }
    free(temp);
}

void print(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
           printf("%d ", array[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    
    int (*array)[3] = malloc(4 * sizeof(*array));
    
    memcpy(array, 
    (int [4][3]){{ 1  ,  1,   1,},
                      {2,    6,   3,},
                      {3,    8,   2,},
                      {4,    9,   1,},}, sizeof(*array) * 4);

    print(4,3,array);
    rotateRow(4,3,array);
    printf("\n --------- \n");
    print(4,3,array);
    free(array);
};
```

```
void rotateRow(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
   
    int temp[cols];
    memcpy(temp, array[0], sizeof(*array));
    memmove(array[0], array[1], sizeof(*array) * (rows - 1));
    memcpy(array[rows - 1], temp, sizeof(*array));
}

void print(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
           printf("%d ", array[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[4][3] = {{ 1  ,  1,   1,},
                      {2,    6,   3,},
                      {3,    8,   2,},
                      {4,    9,   1,},};

    print(4,3,array);
    rotateRow(4,3,array);
    printf("\n --------- \n");
    print(4,3,array);

};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dWMWr5qr3

Comment: I cannot use static arrays, I have to work with malloc because of the amount of memory I have to use change dynamically

Comment: @SimoneRusso and you do not know how to change it. One line of code to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your `memmove` isn't calculating the correct number of bytes to move. This sample does what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS 3
#define ROWS 4

void printDataset(double dataset[ROWS][COLS]) {
     printf ("id\tcol1\tcol2\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
          printf("%.0f\t%.0f\t%.0f\n", dataset[i][0], dataset[i][1], dataset[i][2]);
}

int main() {
     double dataset[ROWS][COLS] = { {1, 1, 1}, {2, 6, 3}, {3, 8, 2}, {4, 9, 1} };
     printDataset(dataset);
     double* temp = malloc(COLS * sizeof(double));
     for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
          temp[i] = dataset[0][i];
     memmove(&dataset[0], &dataset[1], (ROWS - 1) * COLS * sizeof(double));
     for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
          dataset[ROWS - 1][i] = temp[i];
     printDataset(dataset);
     free(temp);
     return 0;
}
```

And here's a pure pointer version that doesn't use static arrays except to initialise the dataset buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS 3
#define ROWS 4

double dataset[ROWS][COLS] = { {1, 1, 1}, {2, 6, 3}, {3, 8, 2}, {4, 9, 1} };

void printDataset(double* dataset, int rows, int cols) {
     printf ("id\tcol1\tcol2\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
               printf("%.0f\t", *(dataset + i * cols + j));
          printf("\n");
     }
}

int main() {
     double* ds = malloc(ROWS * COLS * sizeof(double));
     memcpy(ds, dataset, ROWS * COLS * sizeof(double));
     printDataset(ds, ROWS, COLS);
     double* temp = malloc(COLS * sizeof(double));
     for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
          temp[i] = *(ds + i);;
     memmove(ds, ds + COLS, (ROWS - 1) * COLS * sizeof(double));
     for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
          *(ds + (ROWS - 1) * COLS + i) = temp[i];
     printDataset(ds, ROWS, COLS);
     free(ds);
     free(temp);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're wrong. The memmove is calculating the correct amount of bytes. It seems like the last and the second to last element are pointing to the same pointer. I can't understand if I have to use &dataset or dataset in memmove